# Inverse Function - Determine if exists

Tags: solution-verification, inverse, inverse-function

Determine if an inverse function exists where the function f maps the real numbers to the real numbers by f(x) = $0.5(x+1)^3$ + 2.

I think an inverse function exists if and only if the function is bijective. I sketched the function and it is injective (one-to-one) due to the horizontal line test. To check whether it is surjective I checked whether the image of the graph was equal to the codomain, so the set of real numbers. I think it is, so I believe the inverse function exists.

Would this be correct ?

Comment: If your "I think" and "I believe" are all justified, then yes, it is correct.

Comment: Yes it is correct "thinking". Handsome to know: if $g(x)$ has an inverse and $a\neq0$ then also $ag(x-c)+b$ has an inverse. In that context it is enough to prove that function $x\mapsto x^3$ has an inverse.